# How to deselect link on wkwebview because long press after customized action sheet pop up?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview, uilongpressgesturerecogni

`WKWebView` have native `action sheet` pop up when long press any link on web page, if we long press on any link, when menu action sheet pop up, the pressed link will be deselected automatically.

But I replaced native action sheet with more sharing services, when long press on link, the `![sharing services][1]` will be pop up, but the link not deselected automatically, this will lead user click on link loading another web page seriously if finger move off screen.

How to make it like native action sheet to deselect link automatically when pop up?

[image: Customize and Safari Native]

[image]

Comment: try [webView endEditing:YES]

Comment: How to replace native action sheet with more sharing services, when long press on link?